# Find the velocity of $v$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors, velocity, string

In the arrangement shown in the figure the ends P and Q of an inextensible string moves downward with uniform speed u. Pulleys a and b are fixed. The mass M moves upwards with what speed?

[image: diagram]

How can v be u/cos(theta) as v should be vertical component of velocity u hence v should be u cos(theta)

Comment: It's closed am I allowed to answer this?